# The application buttons of a runnable JAR file do not work in other computers; one of them does not display the chart

Tags: java, jar, bar-chart, jbutton, jfreechart

I have exported an application as runnable JAR file. The window contain three buttons that make specific actions: clear data selection, plot data as bar chart, and plot data as line chart. When I run this file in my computer, both plotting buttons work properly with absolute paths to the respective files (I call the data from .txt files). However, when the runnable JAR file is open in another computer (using the same location in Desktop), the line chart is displayed properly, but the bar chart isn't. The charts are generated using the JFreeChart library.

What could be the reasons for this failure?

The bar chart button retrieves the values selected from a table and placed in text fields. Here is a brief part of the code:

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame implements MouseListener {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    public static JTable table;
    boolean isFirstClick = true;
    private JTextField textFieldYear1;  
    private JTextField textFieldValue1;
    private JButton btnbarChart;    

    public MainWindow() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Application");
        setSize(1500, 800);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        // Methods
        StartComponents();
    }

    public void StartComponents() {

        Icon barChartIcon = new ImageIcon(pathCombined+"barChartIcon.png");
        btnbarChart = new JButton("BarChart",barChartIcon);
        btnbarChart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt1) {
                String year1 = textFieldYear1.getText();
                String Value1 = textFieldValue1.getText();
                                        
                DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
                dataset.setValue(Double.parseDouble(Value1), "Values", year1);
                
                JFreeChart BarChartWindow = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
                    "Application for Plotting Data",
                    "Year",
                    "Values [m³]",
                    dataset,
                    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                    false, true, false);
                ChartFrame barFrame = new ChartFrame("BarChart", BarChartWindow);
                barFrame.setVisible(true);
                barFrame.setSize(500,500);

                CategoryPlot cplot = (CategoryPlot)BarChartWindow.getPlot();
                cplot.setBackgroundPaint(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);

                ((BarRenderer)cplot.getRenderer()).setBarPainter(new StandardBarPainter());
                BarRenderer r = (BarRenderer)BarChartWindow.getCategoryPlot().getRenderer();
                r.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.BLUE);
            }           
        });
        btnbarChart.setBounds(810, 732, 160, 21);
        contentPane.add(btnbarChart);
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt1) {
        DecimalFormat df1 = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
        if (isFirstClick) { 
            int row = table.getSelectedRow();
            String year1 = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
            String Value1 = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 14).toString();
            textFieldYear1.setText(year1);  
            textFieldValue1.setText(df1.format(Double.parseDouble(Value1)));
            isFirstClick = false;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Construct and manipulate Swing GUI objects _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), then please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: Thank you. I realized that other computers could not see the button function for plotting due to the system origin that set the decimal separators as commas, therefore the JFree Chart could not display the plot (no number). Then, I had to specify the Locale.US to keep the decimals with dots instead of commas.